# More efficiënt way for reoccuring modulo?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

**I originally tried this with modulo but it did not work as expected**

It keps giving me back the value(my teacher and I both couldn't figure it out)

Example:

```
 Uw krijgt 200 x 2 euro terug
 Uw Krijgt 100 x 1 euro terug
 Uw krijgt 50 x 50 cent terug
 Etc...
```

**What it's supposed to do**

I need to make a program that calculates howmuch change you get back.

Input 5

Cost: 2

Output: 1x 2 euro, 1x 1 euro, 0 x 50 cents, ...

**My code**

```
int Prijs, Ingegooid;
    int Cent1, Cent2, Cent5, Cent10, Cent20, Cent50, Euro, Euro2, Wisselgeld;





    private void btnCola_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Cent10 = 10;
        Cent20 = 20;
        Cent50 = 50;
        Euro = 100;
        Euro2 = 200;

        Ingegooid = Convert.ToInt32(txbIngegooid.Text);

        Prijs = 190;

        Wisselgeld = (Ingegooid * 100 - Prijs);

        Euro2 = Wisselgeld / Euro2;
        MessageBox.Show("Uw krijgt " + Euro2 + " aantal 2 euro stukken terug.");
        Euro = (Wisselgeld-Euro2*200) / Euro;
        MessageBox.Show("Uw krijgt " + Euro + " aantal 1 euro stukken terug.");
        Cent50 = (Wisselgeld-Euro2*200-Euro*100) / Cent50;
        MessageBox.Show("Uw krijgt " + Cent50 + " aantal 50 cent stukken terug.");
        Cent20 = (Wisselgeld-Euro2*200-Euro*100-Cent50*50) / Cent20;
        MessageBox.Show("Uw krijgt " + Cent20 + " aantal 20 cent stukken terug.");
        Cent10 = (Wisselgeld-Euro2*200-Euro*100-Cent50*50-Cent20*20) / Cent10;


    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Where are you using modulo at all?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Added additional info. I was supposed to use modulo but this was the only way I got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily need modulo for this.
In this case it could actually be misleading.
Example: 90 Cents:
1 possible way to solve this:

1*50c + 2*20c.
Another way would be:
4*20c + 1*10c.

If you want to use the biggest coin whenever possible you could do it this way if you really want to:
    10centAmmount = (change % 50) % 20;
In this case
    10centAmmount = (90 % 50) % 20;
(90 % 50 = 40; 40 % 20 = 0 -> You do not need any 10 cent coins)
Working from the biggest coins to the smallest makes a lot more sense here.
I also recommend substracting the coins you already used from the change. Since the code gets "less crowded"

```
Euro2 = change/200;
change -= Euro2 * 200
Euro1 = change/100
change -= Euro1 * 100
...
```

A use case for modulo would be to figure out whether a number is dividable by any other number.
Example:

```
if (a % 4 == 0) {
    print "a can be devided by 4";
```

Also the code is sort of confusing. You used Euro2 for the amount of cents a Euro coin has, but later you used it to count the number of 2 Euro coins. It would be a little less confusing if you used different variables for this. You could also use constants for values you never need to change, like the cent ammount of 2 euro coins.

Hope this sort of helps.

Comment: Definetely did. Thank-you very much. The confusing with modulo though is that my book explicitly stated to use modulo but I couldn't get it to work mysefl.